# Retrieve php variables passed in Meta Refresh

Tags: php, variables, session, redirect, meta

I am passing php session vars via Meta Refresh. I see the vars posted on the next page in url. How do I take control of them on the new page to use them in a form on that page.

Something along the lines of: (Pseudo Code)

```
(isset($_REQUEST['firstname']){
    $_SESSION['firstname']= $_REQUEST['firstname'];
    echo $_SESSION[firstname];
}
```

This is my code

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['firstname']=$firstname;
$_SESSION['lastname']=$lastname;
$_SESSION['email']=$email;

//$url='/nextpage.php';
//echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV=REFRESH CONTENT="1; '.$url.'">';

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=/nextpage.php?firstname='.$_SESSION['firstname'].'&amp;lastname='.$_SESSION['lastname'].'&amp;email='.$_SESSION['email'].'" />';

exit;
```

Comment: If those values are in your _session_ already, then why would you want to transfer them via URL? That makes no sense.

Comment: you can access your session values in any page you want,by specifying the session_start(); in the starting of the php page

Comment: The page with above code was loaded in the background via an ajax call. The sessions simply wont get passed on to my final page even with session_start(); at the very top of the pages. Had to resort to url passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a scratching and searching for a solution with no luck I finally resolved this way:

```
 <form name="form" id="form" method='post' action='nextpage.php'>

<input type="hidden" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['firstname'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['lastname'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>" />
```

on my next page I assigned the vars to session using post.

```
  $_SESSION['firstname'] = $_POST['firstname'];
  $_SESSION['lastname'] = $_POST['lastname'];
  $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
```

Comment: This is really overly complex for what you're trying to do. Even if they're loaded in a background AJAX call, you should at most have to just refresh the page, and then they'll be accessible through `$_SESSION`.